# How to display and download files from database by clicking a link

Tags: php

the code below was used to display files (.wav files) from database.

My problem is that

1.) I want to display files id from database

2.) i also wanted that when i click on the link to be able to
 download the file from database.

I have added this but could not get it to work as it only shows .wav files on all screen. when you click on download, instead of downloading the files, it will download php file name eg view.php

```
// show file id
echo $f_id = $blob['file_id'];
echo "<a href='$blob_wav'><b style='color:white'>sss</b></a>";
```

can someone help me. Below is the Code

**view.php**

```
<?php

    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'store';

    //Create connection and select DB
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    //Check connection
    if($db->connect_error){
       die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }


    $result = $db->query("SELECT data FROM content");

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $blob = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $blob_wav = $blob['data'];

// show file id
        //echo $f_id = $blob['file_id'];

        header("Content-type: audio/wav"); 

      //echo "<a href='$blob_wav'><b style='color:white'>sss</b></a>";

       echo $blob_wav; 
    }else{
        echo 'blob .wav files not found...';
    }
?>
```

Comment: When you ask a question there is no need to provide useless code like connecting to server part. Also it's better not to use ?> in end of your php

Comment: you need to set the filename using a header. Lots of examples of file downloads online already, you can find dozens of them